# Has OCR functionality on scanned docs in Notes changed?

Tags: ios, notes.app, ocr

In iOS 17.0.3, on the Notes app, I’ve been using the scan document feature to keep a copy of a document, saving within the Note and then copying & pasting elsewhere.

Today, OCR is not working. Works for pictures taken in Notes but not for scanned documents as has been for months.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Did it stop working with the update? What did you try to make it work again? Did you try restarting your iPhone?

Comment: This is pretty easy to reproduce @Thinkr - I’ll poke a bit and try some troubleshooting in case I can find a fix and amend my “yes - doesn’t work today” answer.

Comment: @bmike Oh, thanks for your answer, I can now understand the question xP

Comment: Sounds good and I’m not certain iOS did OCR on these or I got the files to a Mac in the past but it doesn’t work now so it’s either a feature that’s not implemented or a regression.

Answer (score 1):

This function appears to be broken on my iPhone at iOS 17.0.3.

This function is fixed in iOS 17.2 on iPhone and iPad.

---

While it was broken, only the first few words of text are scanned to title the document in my case. Searching for those scanned words doesn’t show any results nor does searching for a word that could be recognized if the document was processed by an OCR engine.

I have to screen shot the document and then copy the text from within the photos app (which is immediately converted).

Comment: Has it been fixed in iOS 17.2?

Comment: Thank you @lhf - I believe it is now fixed. No action on my part taken other than updating - I will edit this answer